# value being constant in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am sorry im not sure that the title makes sense but if u read, im sure u will understand my problem. I have declared a variable  `@State var timetext: Int32` in the file CreatingWorkout, with a textfield `TextField("5000, 100 etc", value: $timetext, formatter: NumberFormatter())` When i go to the createWorkoutView file and try to present it with the sheet, it wants me to give a value to timetext. However, when i provide a value with the textfield it stays constantly value given when calling with the sheet. I will attach a video here for you to see.

CreatingWorkout.swift :

```
struct CreatingWorkout: View {
@State var workoutTitle: String
@State var desc: String
@State var timetext: Int32
@State private var iconColor = Color.black
@State var displayWorkout: String = ""
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

private func saveWorkout() {
    do {
        let workout = Workout(context: viewContext)
        workout.title = workoutTitle
        workout.time = timetext
        workout.icon = displayWorkout
        workout.descriptionn = desc
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

CreateWorkout.swift :

```
import SwiftUI

struct CreateWorkoutView: View {
    @State private var showingCreateWorkout = false
    @State var timetext: Int32 = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Fitzy")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Text("Create your first Workout")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Button {
                        
                        showingCreateWorkout.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("AccentColor"))
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            )
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingCreateWorkout) {
                        CreatingWorkout(workoutTitle: "", desc: "", timetext: timetext)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Create Workout")
        }
    }
}

struct CreateWorkoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateWorkoutView()
    }
}


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQDQmap5bMz9LxzibV98epHW5urqUtZ7/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Please add more code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added more code. If still not enough please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson

Comment: It's still hard to understand why you meant and to reproduce since so much code is missing but if you pass the variable to CreatingWorkout then it needs to be declared as a `@State` property in the calling view and as `@Binding` in CreatingWorkout if you want to retain the value entered in the .sheet. Looking at the code you have posted it looks like the value only lives while the sheet is open.

Comment: The problem is in the CreateWorkout. The sheet, over there ive written .zero and when i try to type in a different value from the simulator, the zero stays a constant. Im asking how to solve that and what to pass in with the timetext.

Comment: And that is what I tried to explain, you need to pass a variable (declared in the view where the sheet is opened from) to the sheet that can hold the entered value once the sheet is closed. Google using State and Binding in SwiftUI.

Comment: Alright so, in 
CreatingWorkout.swift
`@Binding var timetext: Int32
TextField("5000, 100 etc", value: $timetext, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)`
AND
in 
CreateWorkout.swift
`@State var timetext: Int32
Button here
.sheet(isPresented: $showingCreateWorkout) {
                        CreatingWorkout(workoutTitle: "", desc: "", timetext: $timetext)
                    }`

Comment: But it wants a value. And whenever i give a value it stays constant @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, you need a `@State` property to pass the value
that you type in your `TextField` to the sheet with `CreatingWorkout`. Try something like this:

```
struct CreatingWorkout: View {
    @State var workoutTitle: String
    @State var desc: String
    @State var timetext: Int32
    // ....

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(timetext)")
    }
}

struct CreateWorkout: View {
    @State var showingCreateWorkout = false
    @State var timetext: Int32 = 0  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("type a number", value: $timetext, format: .number).border(.red) // <-- here
            Button {
                showingCreateWorkout.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(.red).padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("AccentColor"))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    )
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingCreateWorkout) {
                CreatingWorkout(workoutTitle: "", desc: "", timetext: timetext) // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this however the issue still remains. It is constantly zero, what ur declaring up

Comment: I gave u the whole code in CreateWorkout.swift

Comment: `CreatingWorkout` is a `View`, it must have a body. Try my code as it is, not your code, and tell us if that works. Then we can progress.

Comment: @codepoggies a view without a `body` won’t compile, maybe next time you should tell us you have a compilation error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nah nah, ofc i had a body. Im not stupid, i know swiftui. the textfield and the vars given helped

Comment: @codepoggies I didn't meant to offend you but you said above that you had posted the _whole_ code and there was no `body` so that was my conclusion.